# Split Dataframe into a zip object with n tuples Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization

I'd like to know how to do a function where the input is going to be a list of n columns in a dataframe and output is going to be a zip object with that n columns series, Example

```
def convert_series_into_zip(df,[n1,n2,n2,n3,n2]):
    return zip(df['n1'],df['n2'],df['n3']...)
```

The reason of that is that instead of using vector operations I need loop between n columns in a dataframe and use the ith value of the n series like a tuple (Exactly like the zip function does)

Thank you.

Comment: is it a list of columns _names_? Try `zip(df[n] for n in ['n1', ..., 'n5'])`?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I tried that, and instead of getting tuples with the ith element of every single column I get the entire series

Comment: If you'd like to iterate over dataframe rows as tuples you can use the `itertuples` method. By the way I find the question unclear

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to use a zip function to iterate pandas dataframe because I can put the on  specific columns that I want to iterate, the reason of use zip function is that its faster than an itertuples(), or even iterrows(), the goal on my question is use a dynamic way to put n specifics row in a zip function instead of putting by hand.

Comment: @EternalStudent did you find an answer?

Comment: Sadly, i did not find a solution.